# How to evaluate a list of conditions everytime it is printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, updates

I want to know if there is anyway to evaluate a list of conditions every time the list is printed.

For ex:

```
a,b,c,d=10,15,30,56
li=[a%10==0, b<5, c//3==10, d%2==0]
print(li)
b=3
print(li)
```

The first and second print functions are giving `[True, False, True, True]`

How can I make the list update its values according the conditions mentioned in it above.

So that the second print function prints `[True, True, True, True]` according to the updated value of variable b.

Comment: Use a function to update

Comment: @PatrickArtner, that would work without paranthesis as well.

Comment: @Austin it would? nice to know - and it is cheaper, no tuple construction

Comment: @Tyrion: [why is using eval a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @PatrickArtner, there still is tuple construction. the interpreter will interpret the comma separated list of values as a tuple and then unpack it to the variables.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Same tuple construction.  Tuples are defined by the comma-separated sequence.  Except for empty tuples, parentheses are optional unless required in the particular context.  They are not needed here because assignment '=' binds even more loosely than commas.  `a, b = 1, 2` makes no sense if parsed as `a, (b = 1), 2`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  darn - thx for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Its possible, its called a function:

```
a, b, c, d = 10, 15, 30, 56

def get_list(a,b,c,d):
    return [a%10 == 0 , b < 5, c//3 == 10, d%2 == 0]

print(get_list(a,b,c,d))

b=3
print(get_list(a,b,c,d))
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True, True]
[True, True, True, True]
```

[python lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) would be possible as well - they are lazy bound when executed - hence reflect the changes to `b`:

```
k = lambda: [a%10 == 0 , b < 5, c//3 == 10, d%2 == 0]

print(k())   # execute the lambda
b=3
print(k())   # execute again
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True, True]
[True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to use a function:

```
def evaluate(a, b, c, d):
    return [a%10==0, b<5, c//3==10, d%2==0]

print(evaluate(a, b, c, d))
```